# Replacing a view partial using jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-blade

Laravel Version : 5.6

I want to replace a view partial through an ajax request. I tried using something like

```
$partial = SELF::returnPartial();
return json_encode(['partial' => $partial]);
public function returnPartial(){
    $partial = include \Config::get('view.paths')[0] . '\partials\partial.blade.php';
    return $partial;
    return view('partials.partial');
}
```

And in JS

```
$('.panel-group').html(response.partial)
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: `view('partials.partial' , compact('variable you want to parse'))->render()` hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use render function here

> without variable..

```
return response()->json(['html' => view('partials.partial')->render() ]);
```

> pass variable into view and view send to ajax

```
return response()->json(['html' => view('partials.partial',compact('variableName'))->render() ]);
```

and js code

```
$('.panel-group').html(response.html);
```

for more information read this [article](https://hdtuto.com/article/laravel-return-view-ajax-request-example)

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind response.